# Automatic haskell typeclass instance

Tags: haskell

Here is the simplified sample code to showcase the issue. What I want to do is to get rid of the pattering matching for concrete shape constructor.

```
data Shape a =
        SphereConst (Sphere a)
    |   PlaneConst  (Plane  a)

class GeomShape arg shape where
    intersect :: (Floating arg, Ord arg) => shape -> Ray3d arg -> Maybe (V3 arg)

instance GeomShape a (Plane a) where
    intersect p r = ...

instance GeomShape a (Sphere a) where
    intersect s r = ...
```

Instead of this:

```
instance GeomShape a (Shape a) where
    intersect (SphereConst  s) ray = s `intersect` ray
    intersect (PlaneConst   p) ray = p `intersect` ray
```

I would like to write something like this:

```
instance GeomShape a (Shape a) where
    intersect = intersect :: Sphere a
```

With DeriveAnyClass extension turned on the following code compiles:

```
data Shape a =
        SphereConst (Sphere a)
    |   PlaneConst  (Plane  a) deriving (GeomShape a)
```

However, it crashes with the message: "No instance nor default method for class operation intersect".

To clarify things a bit, type variable "a" serves as a replacement for Double / Float.

Comment: Likely the `GeomShape` should need to work with two parameters, so `class GeomShape sha1 sha2 where`, and then `intersect :: sha1 a -> sha2 a -> Maybe (V3 a)`. In that case, you can "fill the matrix".

Comment: See also the *expression problem in Haskell*:  https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~tom.schrijvers/Research/talks/lhug2.pdf

Comment: I think you'll need to use Template Haskell for this. Generics would need a way to resolve the instance dynamically